# Sum columns for each row of dataframe, and add new column in multi level index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to sum columns for each row on a multi level pandas dataframe, and add the computed values on a new column.

The dataset I'm using is '**flights**' dataset from the seaborn library

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn

# Load dataset from seaborn library
flights = seaborn.load_dataset('flights')

# !!!EDIT - I added this line because it was missing!!!
# Set index for the loaded dataframe
flights_indexed = flights.set_index(['year','month'])

# Unstack the dataframe and create columns for each months
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack()

# Compute sum of each row
sum_row = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)
sum_row_reshape = sum_row.values.reshape(12,1)


### Put the sum of each row in a new column ###
flights_unstacked['passengers','total'] = sum_row

# alternatively,
flights_unstacked['passengers','total'] = sum_row_reshape
```

The above two methods return:

*TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category*

Can anyone help?

Comment: `flights_indexed` variable is never defined? Are you sure it is the complete code?

Comment: My apologies. I missed a line... I've revised the original codes now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the dtype of your month column which is "category". You should convert it to a "str" type. Then your code should work fine:

```
import seaborn
df = seaborn.load_dataset('flights')
print(df.dtypes)
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str)
df.set_index(['year', 'month'], inplace=True)
months = df.index.unique(1)
df_unstacked = df.unstack()
# order of months is lost when using unstack, hence reindex
df_unstacked = df_unstacked.reindex(months, axis=1, level=1)
df_unstacked['passengers', 'sum'] = df_unstacked.sum(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Unstack the dataframe and create columns for each months
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack()
```

The above line ill only create 1 column with 432 rows. Are you trying to create 2 columns? Also the data has has 3 columns namely year, month and passengers. While year and passengers have int values, months has name of months in string. Unstacking will result in you having months in `flights_unstacked` so you probably would have to discard it. Is it really necessary for you to unstack the dataset? Additionally, if you could post you desired outcome, it would be helpful to better understand and answer your question